# How to render a static html from a drupal module

Tags: 6, forms

I need to call a static html page and display the content of it when calling it from the module function , i tried to call from the form api but its just rendering the full markup ,please help

here is the try :

```
$items['mailusers/staticpage'] = array(
    'title' => t('My Static Page'),
    'page callback' => 'my_static_page',
    'access arguments' => array('access GASF admin menus'),
    'access callback' => TRUE,
  );

  return $items;
```

and the function

```
function my_static_page() { 
     $form['html'] =  array(
    '#type' => 'markup',
    '#markup' => //'<h2>My Heading</h2>'
         file_get_contents(drupal_get_path('module', 'mailusers') .'/mailuser.tpl.php'),
  );
 return drupal_render($form);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest way is to create a template file and use [hook_theme](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_theme/7)

1. Put your html in a html-page.tpl.php in your module directory.
2. Use following code to render the html template in your page.

After adding the code make sure you clear your Drupal cache.

```
function my_static_page() { 
  $html = theme('html_page');
  return $html;
}

/**
 * Implements hook_theme().
 */
function your_module_theme($existing, $type, $theme, $path) {
  return array(
    'html_page' => array(
      'template' => 'html-page',
    ),
  );
}
```

Comment: thank you , it should be return $html ;  right , pls correct the answer , i will accept it

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out, I removed "$" by mistake. I have updated the answer. glad it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Go for a template file.
For any page on Drupal you can use template file. You need to place this file in your sites/all/customtheme/templates folder.
Include your markup in the template file for the page n things should start working.

Refer the following link for more details https://www.drupal.org/node/104316&ei=jfCdIMSx&lc=en-IN&s=1&m=114&ts=1438714151&sig=AKQ9UO-epAwDkA_VPfbLQHFr5Xq9KbiCtQ

Comment: page not found !

Comment: Working link: https://www.drupal.org/node/104316